# how can i two custom ol-list in html and css as in the picture

Tags: html, css

[example images of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1VDT.png)

I'm trying to create a list like the image on the side but I don't know how to do it, I want to make 2 lists next to each other that line up in the center of the screen, I tried in other ways and I didn't succeed either.

html:

```
`<div id="wra">
              <ol>
                  <li>
                      <p>Lorem upsum1</p>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                      <p>Lorem upsum imsum huipsum. Lorem upsum imsum huipsum. Lorem upsum imsum huipsum.</p>
                  </li>
              </ol>
          </div>`
```

css:

```
.my-experince {
  display: flex;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#wra {
  margin-left: 50px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ol li {
  height: 60px;
}

ol li p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}

ol:before {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 33px;
}
ol li:before {
  content: "";
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 19px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.test {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to be exactly the same list or two separate lists?

Comment: yes i want it to be exactly the same list or two separate lists

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is not a list at all but a timeline to which you will find many libraries

Comment: @tacoshy what kind of libraries? Be more specific, people come here for help if they knew they wouldn't ask in the first place. Also why reach for a library when it can be done with html css. And what's wrong with a list, what html elements do you suggest?